# give permissions to all actions of all controllers in all the plugins in a cakephp application with Acl

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, acl, php-5.3

let's say that I have a cakePHP application and I would like to use the `allow` method of the [ACL Component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Access-Control-Lists.html) to give permissions to all the actions in all the controllers in all the plugins in the application. I tried something like this:

```
$this->Acl->allow(
    array('model'=>'User', 'foreign_key' => $user_id),
    'controllers'
);
```

and something like this:

```
$this->Acl->allow(
    array('model'=>'User', 'foreign_key' => $user_id),
    'controllers/MyPluginName/controllers'
);
```

But nothing worked. Help please!

**NOTE** : The plugins are in the /app/plugins directory

Comment: Do you really need acl? Most would give you the advice DONT use it if you dont really have to. Use a simpler approach, especially if you need action based access (and not row level).

Answer (score 0):

it will work if your controller actions have 0 as their permission value. cakePHP's permission is bottom to top. i.e if the action is 0, but the controller is 1, you still have access to the action. but if the action is -1, and the controller is 1, then permission is explicitly denied for that action.